# Python regex seems to be incorrectly matching strings

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to use regex in python to match either individual punctuation marks or groups of them. For example, I want to split out punctuation marks like '!?!' and just '@'.

I have the following regex: `` (["#$%&()*+,-/:;<=>@[\]^_`{|}~]|[.?!]+) ``, which does what I want, mostly, except that it seems to capture periods individually (so I get `.` `.` `.` instead of `...`)

What I don't understand is that if I move the `,` character in the first `[]` group somewhere else, it works fine... even if its just one character right or left.

Is there some significance there? Why doesn't it work properly when I have it where it is? (taken from `string.punctuation`)

Thanks in advance. I've searched around and couldn't find anything... so hopefully this isn't too dumb of a question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a character class (the square bracket syntax in regexes), a hyphen means a range of characters.  You have `,-/` in your square brackets, which means it will match any of `, - . /`

Comment: Addendum: to match a literal hyphen in a character class, it needs to be either first, or last: `[a-zA-Z-]` matches any English letter, or hyphen.

Comment: Thank you both. It might have been because of the context but I couldn't see that character as a hyphen for some reason, and didn't understand why the minus sign was causing problems. 

The question was answered too fast for me to accept the answer, but I will do so asap